# Tensorflow - Handling inputs to graph

Tags: python, tensorflow

Background:

I am trying to multiply an tensor of size m by another tensor of size M. I want the result to an mxn tensor

for example:

```
1.0             
         0.2    0.2  0.5
0.0   X       = 0.0  0.0
         0.5    0.2  0.5
1.0
```

**I can do this with numpy:**

```
x_vals = np.array([[1.0, 0.0, 1.0],[0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]])
deltas = np.array([0.2, 0.5])

def Mult(x):
    return x*deltas

#I can do this...
for x in x_vals:
    print Mult(x.reshape(3,1))
```

**I can't do this with tensorflow?**

```
x_vals = np.array([[1.0, 0.0, 1.0],[0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]])
deltas = np.array([0.2, 0.5])

def Mult(x):
    return x*deltas
x = tf.placeholder('float', (None,3))
delta = tf.constant(deltas)
result = Mult(tf.reshape(x, shape=(3,1)))
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# create session and run the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    arr =  sess.run(result, feed_dict={x: x_vals})
```

It seems that it passes in the entire `x_val` array, and I am not sure looping over the session.run for each entry is how its supposed to work. Can anyone give me a pointer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `numpy` it can be simplified as :`x_vals[:,:,np.newaxis]*deltas[np.newaxis,:]`

This should work in tensorflow as well:

```
x_vals = np.array([[1.0, 0.0, 1.0],[0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]])
deltas = np.array([0.2, 0.5])

def Mult(x):
   return x[:,:,tf.newaxis]*deltas[tf.newaxis,:]
x = tf.placeholder('float', (None,3))
delta = tf.constant(deltas)
result = Mult(x)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

# create session and run the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
sess.run(init)
arr =  sess.run(result, feed_dict={x: x_vals})
```

Comment: I see, you expanded the dimensions of the tensor. Thanks